# Sorting game object in front of canvas

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-engine, game-development, unity2.0

how do I sort game object in front of canvas?

notice that Render Mode set to screen space - overlay

hope you have another option instead of change render mode to camera

Comment: What is exactly the problem? Object needs to be 3D or its 2D but renders behind other 2D objects?

Answer (score 3):

UI elements in the Canvas are drawn in the same order they appear in the Hierarchy. The first child is drawn first, the second child next, and so on. If two UI elements overlap, the later one will appear on top of the earlier one.
In case you need to render a 3d gameobject you cannot use the screen space overlay, and need to switch to screen sapace camera.
Everything is very well explained [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/manual/UICanvas.html).

If you could share more details of the concrete problem, what is the outcome of your attempt and what is the result expected, you will be able to obtain more accurate help.