# Make instantiated object visible on canvas

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a canvas, and I'd like an instantiated object to be positioned and visible on it.

In Scene view, it looks like it's right in the middle of the canvas. In Game view, it's not visible.

```cs
GameObject prefab = Resources.Load<GameObject>("cereal");
Vector3 point = new Vector3(0, 0, 10);
GameObject clone = Instantiate(prefab, point, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
clone.transform.parent = canvas.transform;
clone.transform.localScale = new Vector3(100f, 100f, 100f);
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Hellow Joseph, In which coordinates do you have your camera placed? Where is looking at?

Comment: Have you tried instantiating it you can specify parent. By moving it to parent it will adjust the position

Comment: Thank you @AndoniRivera, I can't believe I didn't think to make it a parent of the camera, and not the canvas. Now, I have it positioned correctly. However, my canvas is semi transparent, and I want the instantiated object to appear "on top" of the canvas. Is there any way I can do that?

Comment: I just found an old StackOverflow entry related to your problem. I think that it could help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64509424/sorting-game-object-in-front-of-canvas

Comment: @AndoniRivera I think I understand the answer there, but I've tried making the object a parent of the canvas, and positioning it in the hierarchy in every possible way, and the canvas still appears on top unfortunately

Comment: You might wanna use RenderTexture

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what render mode of canvas you are using.

Canvas has 3 rendering modes Screen Space - Overlay, Screen Space - Camera and World Space

- For **Screen Space - Overlay**, if you want to show an object in the canvas rect you should use `Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint()` to convert the screen position to the world, but you must know where on the screen you want to see the object. Screen position it's position, where **x** in range `0 - Screen.width`, **y** in range `0 - Screen.height`. You must set the distance to the camera yourself.
  **Example:**

> `//Get the center of the screen;`
> `var centerOfTheScreen = new Vector3(Screen.width/2, Screen.height/2);`
> `var camera = Camera.main;`
> `var distance = camera.transform.forward * 10;// here you can set prefered distance;`
> `var objectPosition = camera.ScreenToWorldPoint(centerOfTheScreen) + distance;`
> `var instance = Instanitate(prefab, objectPosition, Quaternion.identity);`

- For **Screen Space - Camera** you can use world position of the camera. In this mode no need to convert screen to world position, camera position will be enough. You can use distance calculation form the previous mode (`var distance = camera.transform.forward * 10;`) and add it to the camera position. It`s will looks like:

> `var camera = Camera.main;`
> `var distance = camera.transform.forward * 10;// here you can set prefered distance;`
> `var objectPosition = camera.transform.position + distance;`
> `var instance = Instanitate(prefab, objectPosition, Quaternion.identity);`

- For **World Space** you can directly use world position of the canvas gameobject, but, I think, it`s not you case. Just use canvas position instead camera.
  **Example:**

> `//This code snippet create object benind canvas. If you want create object on canvas - remove distance`
> `var distance = canvas.transform.forward * 10;// here you can set prefered distance;`
> `var objectPosition = canvas.transform.position + distance;`
> `var instance = Instanitate(prefab, objectPosition, Quaternion.identity);`

**UPD:** If you want to make an object the child of a canvas transform, you can use `instance.transform.SetParent(canvas.transform, false)` and after that use the calculation described above. For the **World Space** canvas it will be even easier.